# How to set up environment variable PATH while installing MinGW (Windows 32-bit)

Tags: c++, installation, environment-variables, mingw, mingw32

I am trying to install the [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compiler (to be followed by Eclipse IDE) for C++ in my Windows 32-bit machine.

For the MinGW installation, I am trying to follow the page *[How to install MinGW-w64 GCC Compiler](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html#mingw)*.

Here, Step 3 says:

> Setup environment variable PATH to include "MINGW_HOME/bin" where MINGW_HOME is the MinGW installed directory that you have chosen in the previous step.

If I have chosen D:\MINGW as the directory here, how do I perform step 3? I don’t understand where/how to set this particular environment variable up.

Answer (score 1):

The path variable is basically just a list of all places Windows searches for commands when they're typed into the command line.  Commands related to MinGW won't be recognized unless you tell Windows the location of the directory containing those commands.

You do this by adding `;<directory location>` to the end of the path variable.  If you installed MinGW in *D:\MINGW*, you should add `;D:\MINGW\bin`.